# Redirect user to default error page in spring

Tags: spring-mvc

I need to redirect user to a specific error page in someone modifies the url

for Ex:-  if someone change the url from `http://localhost:8085/PSST/PSS` to `http://localhost:8085/DLMS_Client/PS` then application should redirect the user to a default error page.

I am struggling for the solution from past few days.

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use `SimpleExceptionMappingResolver` of Spring . You need to set this in your `projet-servlet.xml`

```
<!-- ExceptionResolverMapping: generate exception specific view -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="com.rail.eseva.exception.UnexpectedException">/unexpectedExceptionView</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultErrorView" value="/genericExceptionView"/>
    </bean>
```

create a custom exception class like-

```
public class UnexpectedException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private String message;
    private Date date;
    public UnexpectedException(String message, Date date) {
        this.date=date;
        this.message=message;
    }
    /**
     * @return the message
     */
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    /**
     * @return the date
     */
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return message +" "+date.getTime();
    }
}
```

and generic exception view page

```
<body>

    <h2>Exception occured at: <fmt:formatDate value="${exception.date}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/></h2>
    <h2>Exception message :</h2> ${exception.message} 

</body>
```

now you can throw this exception as per your requirement :

```
throw new UnexpectedException(e.getMessage(), new Date());
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. In my case if someone modify the url then how to display that default error page. In that case controller name will not found. Then I need to show the default error page.

Comment: If this not a valid URL then Page will not be display(browser own function) else if this is valid URL and you dont want to process it then you can handle the logic in your controller.